# Developer Survey 2023 - full data set availability?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, survey, survey-2023

Currently, https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey links to the results summary of this year's developer survey and the summaries and full data sets of previous years:

[image: Cropped screenshot of the insights survey homepage, showing the links mentioned above]

Is there a plan to release the full data set for this year's survey?

I couldn't find any mention that the release of the dataset is delayed until a specific date.

I also see that other changes have been made in the name of privacy (for example [to the Census badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424491/updated-2023-may-8-changes-to-the-census-badge), and a probably [unrelated issue with the quarterly SO dump](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424299/stack-overflow-is-no-longer-providing-creative-commons-data-dumps/425121#425121)), so it wasn't clear whether the lack of a full dataset is related to privacy concerns.

In any case, some clarity (or a link to where the clarity already exists) is appreciated.

Comment: Especially considering the fact that we found couple of concerning "stats": https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZRHq.png -- credit goes to VLAZ -- https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56433363

Comment: I _thought_ we tracked this in [the canonical post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396864), but alas that only tracks the official survey open, close, and first results announcement, not the dataset release.

Comment: @zcoop98 Thanks for that link, I did see it beforehand but you gave me the idea to go back and check around those dates in the Wayback machine to see if there was a delay last year too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [noted by Gareth](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425310/developer-survey-2023-full-data-set-availability/425331#425331) (thanks for the assist!), the full data set not being available as soon as the survey results are posted is correct.

Typically, it takes several weeks before the [insights page](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey) is updated with the current year's full data set.

I'll update this post letting folks know when this year's set has been added once that's been done.

**[UPDATE]** The 2023 full data set has been added to the [Survey insights page](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey).

Answer (score 9):

Although there is no information about when this is going to be released for 2023, it's not expected that the full data set is released at the same time as the results summary is published.

Looking at [the Wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20220801000000*/https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey), the 2022 survey results were released on June 22nd, 2022, but the full data set didn't appear until some time between [July 12th, 2022](https://web.archive.org/web/20220712060151/https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey) and the next capture on [July 31st, 2022](https://web.archive.org/web/20220731141102/https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey).

There didn't seem to be any specific announcement about the release, even in a blog post from [July 27th, 2022](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/07/27/always-learning/) that heavily featured survey analytics, so I couldn't find a public way to be sure about the date.

In any case, the fact that the results aren't immediately available doesn't necessarily indicate that anything is different with this year's survey.

(I'm answering this myself after more research, but I'm not accepting this answer because maybe someone official will have more information on this year's survey)