# An old Meta Hound approaches the bowl one more time

Tags: discussion

I know I'm not that important, or that I matter all too much to the network, but I've given this a bit of thought from over the summer, and I've come to a conclusion.

Effective as of 1 January 2024, I'll cease being active on the site and will stop contributing entirely to Stack Overflow and the other network sites.

What led me to this decision were a handful of factors.

1. **The company's ham-fisted and impotent response to AI.**  There was so much energy exerted over this bogeyman of an AI creature, which resulted in so much *wasted* energy, from [stopping the archives](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390023/175248) to then using that as [some kind of mystical justification to be able to charge for data](https://www.wired.com/story/stack-overflow-will-charge-ai-giants-for-training-data/) when AI already had the data they were trying to lock up.  Worse yet, all of the claims in there couldn't have possibly been actioned, since [Stack Overflow doesn't serve as copyright cop](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424312/1079354).  For insult to injury, instead of doing the most sensible thing when it came to people posting AI-generated answers looking for a quick hit of unicorn points, we instead have to kind of cage around that with explicit rules and heuristics instead of a firm "no AI answers allowed, thank you very much".
2. **Whatever the heck this "Collectives" thing is.**  I'm too burnt out to go into further elaboration [anymore than I already have](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1079354+collectives), but c'mon.  The feature is not going down well with the community.  You don't even know what it's meant to be anymore.
3. **The sheer amount of brain drain has left me with no confidence in the future direction of the organization.**  Y'all lost so many talented and effective staff in the last three years alone, and with the most recent round of layoffs, [the words you've said don't even land with me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393806/practical-effects-of-the-october-2023-layoff/393839#comment1317061_393839).
4. Probably the most practical, **I find Q&A to be boring.**  When I was a Learning Assistant Tech, working in my university's Accessibility Center, I could come to Stack Overflow for that hit of dopamine in helping someone solve their problem.  Nowadays, we've had so many people who just demand that we help them with their problems (and if we don't, they get huffy and ask ChatGPT and *then* come back to ask us) that it's just a mental drain.  We've been asking for better ways to engage with people, over and over and over again to the point that it's not worth linking any of the conversations.  Because of this lack of enthusiasm to be called - once more - some kind of "jerk" with some kind of "agenda" against their "learning" or "development", I'll just shut up.
5. **The company - mostly upper leadership - feels like it's lost its soul.**  This is an obvious one to throw in there but I'll do so for good measure; in all reality, the place doesn't have very good vibes left to it.  Leadership is motivated chiefly by "line goes up" metrics, and doesn't feel like they're that vested with us.

I'm still foolishly holding out hope that the place can turn itself around, but I don't think I want to be mentally burdened with it any longer, so in the new year I'll (likely) sign out of my accounts and just use the site like every other Googler that comes this way.

Those of you who wish to stay in touch would know where to find me.

Comment: I honestly wish that posts like this would make even a slight dent, but I'm too realistic to hold much hope. Regardless, good luck to you and fare thee well.

Comment: No, sadly this won’t even reach the door, to make the dent. We will miss you Makoto!

Comment: I don't know whether to upvote as a "good for you" or downvote as a "bad for us". I value your contributions, particularly the direct-speak keen insights. This is another big network loss and another positive role model gone.

Comment: I don't know what to say.... I am really sad to see you go and I will certainly miss you. But, I fully understand your decision, and your thoughts might as well be mine.

Comment: Point 4 is kind of interesting in that people seem surprised by it. Most healthy communities will experience passing through them, drawn in by interest and curiosity, but eventually that curiosity is satisfied and the people should move on. But often we stay well past the point when we should leave, burnt out, jaded, disappointed, and just kind of...make things worse for everyone. I'm definitely one of those people :)

Comment: *"I could come to Stack Overflow for that hit of dopamine in helping someone solve their problem"* - I think this is key. I totally recognise that. Stack Overflow is... just not fun anymore. There are arguments for everything; it fills a gap other sites don't, the knowledge base is full, bla bla bla. It doesn't matter at all though. It's not fun. It's too hard to answer something and not fret. Is it a duplicate, does it pass all the ambiguously defined rules, will it be well-received, is it AI generated. It's too tiring.

Comment: I don't know why you wrote that you find Q&A boring, because in truth you don't. Rather, when you have to deal with 99 help vampires to interact with 1 person who gives you a dopamine hit, you end up running a massive dopamine deficit - and human beings physically can't operate like that.

Comment: Also, Makoto, I am obviously sad to see you go. You're one of the real ones. Regardless of how bad you feel now, regardless of how futile the time and effort you put into this site may seem - know that those of us who walked this path with you, shared this vision with you, will always cherish and remember your part in the attempt to build something different and special.

Comment: "I know I'm not that important, or that I matter all too much to the network". I object.

Comment: I never left, but the quantity of my contributions is way down, and I stopped caring about half the quality metrics. They can't learn except by school of hard knocks.

Comment: I'd ask the question - how many more core members can the network afford to lose, either like this or "quiet quitting" before the folks who run the company realise they're literally destroying the value it has. Sadly I feel like we'll only find the answer once its too late. We can less afford to loose good community members and line staff than an anything else.

Comment: One thing that comes to remembrance is your ability to accept that you were wrong, which I felt was completely opposite to the general direction of meta/socvr.  When I explained how you were wrong, you [deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420699/are-questions-specific-to-excel-vbas-ide-considered-on-topic/420701#comment929644_420699) your answer, even though it was more popular and had more votes than me. That left a impression. Bye. Take care.

Comment: Sad. You will be sorely missed. I always hope that [one of these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393795) announcements can be the wake-up call for decision-makers in this company. Hope is the last to die, I guess. Probably even after the site has died. About the boring Q&A, [this recent article by ex-Community Advocate Yaakov Ellis](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/what-i-would-do-ran-stack-overflow-product-yaakov-ellis-y7fnf) makes a very similar point.

Comment: I left the community due to the hostility from new users, expecting an answer to their questions, no matter the quality of them. Until the community positively rejects AI generated answers I plan on remaining in that state. I have unresolved flags for AI content from 6-9 months ago. Despite the policy against AI generated content the fact the flags are unhandled suggests AI created content is allowed.

Comment: @SecurityHound: I was assured by an active mod (a few weeks ago) that the mod queues were still fit to bursting, and their levels were not going down because (a) some report investigation is time-consuming, and (b) moderation activity levels were taking a long time to come back after the last strike. I suspect that, as in my case, your very old reports have been pushed down by newer ones.

Comment: *so in the new year I'll (likely) sign out of my accounts*: PLEASE DON'T. You are one of those community members who are not afraid at all to strongly express their believes, not caring to earn criticism in comments or via Meta-DVs. Your voice is needed here. It is needed here and makes a difference (it always has)

Comment: @halfer - They could also be purposely being ignored. I don’t actually know. Just know even my recent ChatGPT flags have been ignored.

Comment: @SecurityHound: that was my concern, I thought I'd been blacklisted. But I was assured that this was not the case.

Comment: @SecurityHound Nothing is being purposely ignored. It is just that site is overrun by AI posts and new rules are still not polished enough to give mods smooth ride in dealing with AI posts. Having said that, using AI is forbidden and no matter how old the answers are, they will be dealt with sooner or later.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Sadly, you know the answer. Company does not care. No matter how many valuable users are gone, none will make a dent or be able to change their course not even the slightest. They are confidently sailing to the bottom of the sea and there is nothing we can do about it.

Comment: I can sign all five points. I still like to keep signed in. You never know when you stumble upon that well written and highly upvoted Q&A with this simple to fix typo that can be fixed in a few seconds if only someone had the power to edit. I want to keep that edit power and maybe comment on meta from time to time. But I have little to no hope for a better future for SO and the network. In all likelihood things will go further downhill from here.

Comment: I haven't participated in SO since the Monica affair.  Always was surprised that you had so much patience with them!  Just wanted to say, you have always been one of the best things about SO, sensible without being sanctimonious. Good luck in the future, hope you can reclaim a lot of time for new projects and a happy life, you deserve it.

Comment: Welcome to the retirement camp, the grass is greener on this side.

Comment: Thanks for standing up for all of us so many times over the years on Meta when a lot others (myself included) couldn’t bring up the energy anymore. Thanks for everything and see you around somewhere else!

Comment: This is a huge loss, you will be missed @makoto

Comment: Best wishes from another pissed-off long-termer.  TBH, I'm surprised that there are any skilled and experienced engineers left to prop up the homework vamps:(

Comment: I simply cannot stop watching the company from the sidelines and it's like watching a train crash in very slow motion. Some wheels are still turning (update on tag colors even with gathering feedback which is really exemplary) while all essential parts (those important for dealing with the content) are standing absolutely still for a long time now.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar - They will just let AI answer the questions and when that happens will be worse than Yahoo Answers and Quora combined which is very hard to do since both those websites try really really hard to suck as much as they do. AI is totally the future…..says only the people, who never were able to do their own work or create anything themselves.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Gonna miss seeing your posts, but I'll echo Steve Bennett's comment: reason #4 is the best reason to walk away, and I respect you quite a bit for facing up to that.

It's easy to forget, but... [This was supposed to be fun](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), a much-needed diversion from serious work that happened to have a side benefit of helping others. Like a charity poker run or something. When you don't get to drink or ride motorcycles or win prizes anymore, that's not a fun way to donate your time to charity, it's just... Donating time. Doing work. Work that gets you [paid in attention](https://www.roughtype.com/?p=634). Attention that is mostly negative.

If [the goal here is to provide a comfortable place for the oysters so that the sand may have a purpose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285096/does-the-se-network-have-any-special-occasions-for-this-day/285097#285097), then feeling like you're eating handfuls of sand is a good sign that this is no longer the oysterbed you thought it might be. Time to flee...

> "O  Oysters," said the Carpenter,
> "You've had a pleasant run!
> Shall we be trotting home again?"
> But answer came there none —
> And this was scarcely odd, because
> They'd eaten every one.
>
> – Lewis Carroll, "The Walrus and the Carpenter"

Answer (score 33):

Once one has volunteered at a community for a sufficient length of time, the contributions become a normal habit, to the degree that tearing oneself away becomes a peculiar psychological wrench. It creates a void that needs filling with something else.

I [pondered that theme here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425722/how-can-we-handle-troublesome-contributors-during-the-moderation-strike) on why I keep curating. There is something of the "[someone is wrong on the internet](https://xkcd.com/386/)" about it - the work is simultaneously satisfying, useful, and futile. We know full well we're baling an ocean out with a cup, and yet we keep doing it.

I don't disagree with anything in your post, and you'll be missed because of your ability to join the dots in this fashion. But I am amused at permitting myself to be captured by that force of habit, possibly because Stack Overflow is still the best at what it does on the web. AI could well up-end that in few years, and maybe that is what is driving all this confusing corporate flux. A company of this scale surely doesn't care about its volunteer base, but it does not have the capacity to, since volunteer labour is not a line-entry on a P&L report. We might not care for the company either, and probably never have: we just want to help other engineers, free of charge, simply because we enjoy helping. Dopamine has a lot to answer for.

I did find one ray of optimism in the Wired story: Stack Overflow might start using AI to help new contributors ask questions. AI is dreadful for creating answers, but as training wheels for help vampires, it might actually do some good.

Comment: AI might also help people pose close-worthy questions which initially seem like they aren't...

Answer (score -15):

Rumour has it, [they are going to sell the company](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393824/237804). Assuming this is true:

1. After that happens, you might want to reconsider.
2. Of course, they only care for things which sell well! Those things which you care about, don't.

Comment: It looks like this was supposition, rather than rumour. I don't disagree with the thesis, but there's no evidence yet IMO.

Comment: What does that have to do with this? We've been under new management since the site was bought and that led us to this moment a lot faster overall IMO, whoever else comes along to buy this would likely want their investment doubled even faster