# Why have I started seeing really old answered questions that are edited more?

Tags: discussion, homepage, last-activity

Why, and how can I not see as I have been recently seeing old (really old?) questions pop up on the home/default page where someone edited it but it already has an accepted answer; only the question was edited to add clarity (while great I don't really want/need to see it perhaps).

This question was edited and popped up like it might need some "attention" but merely served to distract from newer questions that have not yet been answered/received much attention.

Example: This previously answered/accepted question was edited to add clarity
[Strips Menu with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2415480/125981)

**EDIT:** Perhaps some confusion here this is NOT about the edit; that is fine and desired.  This is more about not seeing it pop up on the home page "Top Questions" when it already has an accepted answer rather than other recent unanswered questions.

This may not be a "new" factor but I have recently (past month or so) noticed it a small number of times (a dozen approx.) as I peruse for some questions I might provide a quick answer for, things like that.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26483/could-we-have-the-ability-to-mark-a-change-as-minor-in-questions-or-answers

Comment: Confirmation bias? The active homepage on SO has been like this as long as I can remember (years and years).

Comment: I have to ask? The one example of the edit did improve the quality of the question. So how is it bad to edit questions that can be improved?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Newest

Comment: I'm the editor in this case. I definitely stand by this edit - the new one is much more readable. However the general point about kicking recently edited items to the front page is not a bad item to raise. I take the view that bumping this is a choice from the designers of the system - in other words I didn't bump it with my edit, but someone decided that edits cause it to be bumped. Bumping is good since it ensures edits are not destructive, but bumping is bad because some people like to monitor the front page for "new" content.

Comment: We could have a system where experienced editors cause less of a bump (or no bump at all), but how should we measure "experience"? There are definitely some high-rep users who follow only their own rules, and centre their purpose for being here as testing the generally-accepted rules of the community. Maybe the top 50 editors? I don't know - comments on this theme welcome.

Comment: @halfer the real question is why not vote to close a question that boils down to "my code is at link *x*, I want it to look like link *y*"

Comment: @miken32: it's an interesting question, but I myself am anxious not to commit volunteers to additional labour. I already undertake a foolhardy amount of editing and voting curation, and I would be wary of any opinions that require me to do more than I am already doing. I am already [baling the ocean out with a cup](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/427541).

Comment: @halfer understood, I am in the same ocean and didn't mean to put down your efforts. Just seemed like it would be *less* work to VTC questions like that. Apologies if I came across badly.

Comment: @miken32: oh not at all, it's fine. I think I do sometimes VtC on stuff that is obviously terrible, but unless there is collaborative close voting, votes to close often die on the vine. Currently my approach is to search for trigger words and then do a long string of edit improvements, and thus topicality does not always get tested. Perhaps I should though; I will ponder on it.

Comment: (I tend to think of editing and voting as orthogonal. So I would not vote to close instead of editing, it would nearly always be additional. Closed questions can still survive for years).

Comment: Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. (And adding to something unclear doesn't make it clear.)

Comment: @halfer - Specifying an edit has happened on a SE contribution isn’t necessary. Please don’t do it. It’s extra work for editors. Any edit proposal that has “edit” or “update” will instantly be rejected by this editor.

Comment: Maybe a "show tickbox to mark my edit as trivial/don't bump" privilege could be added at, say, 7500 points.

Comment: @halfer *"in other words I didn't bump it with my edit, but someone decided that edits cause it to be bumped"*. I love that take and it is exactly true. It is the same as  reputation points. We're not dishing them out or taking them away, we're voting on post quality. What happens as a result of making that vote is not our decision and thus out of our hands. BUT the consequences of doing it on-mass are invasive, so it is understandable that boundaries are set to contain the people that cannot contain themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes curators take it upon themselves to make batch improvements to old questions upon a common theme. Depending on the nature of the changes, this could "bump" a large fraction of them.

Nowadays this is perhaps more noticeable because the rate of new questions has been fairly steadily declining since 2014 or so (and low-quality questions are *somewhat* more quickly downvoted and closed), but it's still more or less random chance if you're around at the same time that something like this is happening.

Comment: related commentary: I have a problem with doing things overeagerly, and have gotten in trouble (rightly so, about a year ago) for rapidly bumping an obscene number of posts with trivial cleanup edits (what I mean to say is, don't make that same mistake). Also, many of my own posts contain (important) "boilerplate", and there have been times when I've felt it important or been asked to update those boilerplate bits, resulting in lots of bumps in a short span of time to Q&A I've answered.